Do professors normally explicitly state on their web page that they aren't taking new applicants?
Do they? Otherwise there is a big risk of applying to their departments and programs (implying paying the admission fee) and listing them as potential supervisors but later on getting to know that they don't have any open positions? Also many professors don't reply to emails asking for open positions.
P.S: I am majorly talking about Canadian universities where it isn't mandatory to secure a supervisor before applying.
update:
My field is Electrical Engineering forgot to mention.

You should never take the absence of a specific signal as a strong indicator of anything. Culture varies too much for that.

Then what should one do? Not apply to universities unless the professors reply to emails?

In general, I would take the position that people are taking students unless they say they aren't. But, I'm not in your field or country (although I have a little experience). To your question in the comments ... yes, I wouldn't, but the above caveats apply.

I can't speak for the Canadian system, but in many systems (like the UK system) you would know who your supervisor would be before you paid the admission fee.

Most professors seem to update their web pages about once every 5 years or so when the administration rolls out a new format and forces them to...

@JonCuster In my case, it was the opposite. I would update my page regularly, until the admin rolled out a new format which is inconvenient and unflexible to manage.

@CaptainEmacs - so your next update will be in about 5 years or so?

Only one datapoint, but: my web page explicitly states that I am not currently taking on new applicants for students (or RAs) - it hasn't had any effect on the number of unsolicited inquiries I get AFAICS.

@JonCuster Google Scholar is so kind and does it for me, on the things that matter most...

Given that most professors' websites are years out of date, empirically the answer is "no, professors do not normally state (up to date) information about whether they do or do not accept students".

The short answer: depends.
The long answer: some very high-profile profs will say that they do not accept students or only through the programme, as they may get dozens of requests every day. But, by default, that's not what a prof will say, as they do not want to deter strong students.
If a prof does not respond it could be because:

they do not read their email
they do not read cold emails
the spam filter removes cold emails
they are not interested
they would be interested if they paid attention, but get too many requests
your mail was read, marked as relevant and forgotten
they already have enough students
[enter your own reason here]

My recommendation is, when applying, to make sure that one has a supervisor lined up. If it is not possible, make sure that at least you propose a research programme compatible with the work in the department. Read the papers of the group you are interested in and apply in that direction.
Personally, I think it is very problematic that a programme would accept PhD students without securing a supervisor/research group first. This borders on the unethical, in my opinion. It can end with a student ending up with an unmotivated topic-indifferent supervisor who the student has been foisted upon.

Yes I agree but this is the trend with most Canadian universities or atleast the ones which I have explored. So should one apply to such programs or not?

@Candy that depends on what your options are. If you get a choice between a perfect and less than perfect option, then you should take the perfect option. But almost always the choice is between an option that is imperfect in one way and another option that is imperfect in another way. Moreover, the imperfections are often unknown to you when you make the decision.

"a programme would accept PhD students without securing a supervisor/research group first" This varies by field a lot. In math, it is very normal to accept students without securing a research group. My friend who is a neuroscientist tells this basically never happens in her field. We could have a long argument about which system is better, but from the graduate applicants perspective, what matters is that they need to say what field they are on in order to know whether this is a red flag or normal.

@DavidESpeyer In math, how does that work practically? In Germany, that's definitively not the case, as far as I can tell.

@DavidESpeyer At least in neuroscience in the US, it depends on whether there is funding for "rotating" students, often through a NIH training grant. So, even within fields it varies.

@MaartenBuis In the US maths PhD-programmes are usually combined masters+PhD programs. Even if you already have a masters degree you have to join for the whole program. In the first 1 or 2 years of the program you take advanced classes and have to pass qualifying exams. You get to know different areas of maths and the professors, the professors get to know the PhD students. Somewhere during that time the matchup between professors and students happens.

My experience (math, US, late 1980s) is that, for the reasons David Speyer listed, math grad students need to spend at least a year studying more math, basically to upgrade their background from typical US BSc to MSc level before they have any idea what math is at the research level (and which area appeals to them). Assigning student to an advisor in advance is then somewhere between a blind date and meeting your spouse for the first time at the altar. Of course, easier with the stronger students. Anyway, grad students then shop for supervisors (and to some extent vice versa)

@JyrkiLahtonen That makes sense if the allocation happens only after one year. What I know from the UK, however, is that they get assigned immediately. In Germany, I found that profs tend to prefer students they know for a while. So, the "altar bride" scenario is definitively more common in the UK. Again, YMMV.

Personally, I do not state when I am not taking students. This is because I want to keep the door open for when an exceptional candidate comes along. Even if I do not have space, I will find a way. I will co-supervise with one of my colleagues who does have space, etc... I will secure a TA position to start if I have no RA spots left, etc.. I have done this in the past and that is how I got some of my best students.
Unfortunately, for 99% of my cold emails, I will either ignore when I have too many (or they are too impersonal), or I will simply reply with a "sorry, unfortunately we do not have any openings". Which is honest, because I do not actively have openings I need to fill, but I am still willing to field enquiry and can be persuaded to create them for the right person.

But then do you reply actively to the exceptional candidates and tell them to go ahead with the formal application process?
